# PartialMock for Init method

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

I've tried swizzling out the init method for a partial mock and was wondering if this was possible.

I've had no luck with:

```
SomeClass *foo = [SomeClass alloc];
mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:foo];
[[[mock stub] andCall:@selector(mockInit) onObject:self] init];
```

...

```
[foo init];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call the init method, you shall it on your mock instance. I think it will work if you do this:

```
SomeClass *foo = [SomeClass alloc];
mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:foo];
[[[mock stub] andCall:@selector(mockInit) onObject:self] init];
```

...

```
[mock init];
```

Regards,
Quentin